# Prevent deletion of all data after 10 incorrect unlock attempts

Tags: lock-screens, 7.1-nougat

"You've incorrectly attempted to unlock the phone 1 times. After 9 more unsuccessful attempts, this phone will be reset, which will delete all its data."

This is actually worse than just letting the attacker access my data, because now I can't get at it either.

As such, this lockscreen is actually worse than not having a lockscreen.

This phone is a (Tracfone) Alcatel (TCT) A577VL (supposedly a Pixi 5 HD), and it doesn't appear to be rootable easily.

1) How do I get rid of this feature, or replace the lockscreen application, without rooting?

2) The A577VL (Pixi 5?) does not appear to officially exist according to Alcatel; can I root it to fix this more easily?

[image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click image for larger variant)</sup>

Comment: "This is actually worse than just letting the attacker access my data, because now I can't get at it either." – I disagree. This is security – and for the second part, you have a backup. Haven't you? // As for "getting rid": Do you want to disable the lock screen completely (which can easiliy be done via settings) – or just disable the deletion part (which might be achieved by disabling the integrated lock and using a 3rd party lock screen)?

Comment: "This is actually worse than just letting the attacker access my data, because now I can't get at it either." If an attacker gets hold of your phone, I assure you that you aren't going to get it back, nor will you be getting the data from it unless you have everything backed up somewhere.

Comment: @Izzy to answer your question, i've clarified the first point

Comment: @MichaelKohne i'm far more concerned about the case in which someone (a fellow student, or an unruly young family member,  for example) just sabotages my phone by abusing this feature -- they know they would get in more trouble for stealing it (or it would be inevitable that I get it back) than trying to unlock it, so they would just leave it where I left it, having succeeded in their harassment. alternatively, having factory reset the phone, now it is their device, freshly from the factory, and not my device, and there's nothing i can do to prove ownership short of the removable serial number

Comment: OK, valid points, @cat – take a look at my [lockscreens app listing](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_lockscreen) then. Personally, I'd avoid those with too many permissions (numbers in the square boxes next to the app name) – especially CM (Cheetah) and GO (both: ads, trackers: mouse-over the "monitor icons" in those lines for details). "C Locker" is a good one, though. Haven't tried the others.